# Не работает htaccess в Bitrix

Tags: битрикс, apache2

1C Bitrix v12.
Требуется на каталог ограничить доступ и дать некоторым.
PS Override all (в конфиге)
запихнул .htaccess и .htpasswd в каталог к которому нужно ограничить доступ(к файлам)

.htaccess

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "pravila"
AuthUserFile "c:\Program Files(x86)\....\pravila\test1\.htpasswd"
require valid-user
```

.htpasswd соответственно логин и кодированный пароль (всю генерю через cmd спомощью ... -m ... )

Но на сайте никаких ограничений к файлам нет... Компонент: комплексный компонент библиотеки документов для работы с инфоблоками.

Answer (score 1):

А зачем это делать вручную, когда есть настройка прав на папки и файлы в файловой структуре в админке из коробки?